# Can you change Ruby core classes (eg String) in a Ruby on Rails deployed on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I ran into a problem with adding a method to `String` that allows you to do something like: `"9".is_a_number?` and get `true` or `false`. I tested it working on development but when I pushed to production it didn't work.

Anybody have experience changing Ruby core classes on Heroku?

Both times I placed the new code inside the /helper directory on my Rails app.

**Edit:**

This is from my memory so I don't have 100% confidence that this is what I had:

`app/helpers/sudoku_helper.rb`

```
class String
   def is_a_number?
      self.to_f.to_s == self.to_s || self.to_i.to_s == self.to_s
   end
end
```

I didn't add anything else, as it worked on development. Perhaps I need to do something to tell Rails to run it on production?

Comment: indeed it does work. There should be no difference from the local environment for this example.

Comment: Ok maybe I did something wrong because it gave me a no method error when I checked the logs. Both times I placed the code inside the /helper directory. Perhaps it wasn't required automatically on production?

Comment: in rails `/helper` is not autoloaded. You can use `heroku run rails c` to check. Why not post your code excerpt including the file path.

Comment: I updated it. Thanks Max.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in the `lib` folder and require it in a initializer or directly put your code in the initializer.
This way, you can be sure it is loaded and when is it loaded.

Comment: I just plugged in "010" into the code and it worked. Are you sure? Even if it doesn't work though, it should be OK because I limited the input for my Sudoku solver. Thanks.

Comment: Confusion about number notation, you're right ! I removed this part from my post